# AWS Cognito User Pool with Facebook - example app failing - AmazonCognitoIdentity is not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, amazon-cognito

Using AWS Cognito User Pool with Facebook provider - test link working fine. Now i was looking example app for UI which uses Cognito SDK and found this:
https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/blob/master/sample/index.html

This  app had several mistakes, fixed them all but now failing on this one:
ReferenceError: AmazonCognitoIdentity is not defined
Indeed. Where can i find it ?
It looks like obsolete code, do we have any other example using Facebook login ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you download the amazon-cognito-auth-js file and put it in dist folder?

Comment: Yep, had that js, fixed few minor things, i still do not have it working, but i do believe it's issue with Cognito service, asked a question on aws forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=306333. Thanks !